# Failed to convert an image data URI into an array of pixel data

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64, data-uri

I want to convert base64 datauri to image data without using html5 canvas. To do that i have written following code.

  `// Here i have converted datauri to base64
  var b64 = datauri.slice(exifModified.indexOf(',')+1);
  // here i have converted base64 to string
  var str = atob(b64);
  // here i have converted string to array
  var arr = str.split('').map(function (e) {return e.charCodeAt(0);});
  // here i have created uint8clampedarray 
  var u = new Uint8ClampedArray(arr); // [255, 56, 201, 8]
  // here i have created image data by using uint8clampedarray
  var data = new ImageData(u,1000,1000);`

But i could not able to create image data. I got the following error.
`Failed to construct 'ImageData': The input data byte length is not a multiple of 4.`
I have observed that here uint8clampedarray length is not multiple of 4 i.e, 2163747.
Could anyone knows why uint8clampedarray lenght was not multiple of 4 please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Kaiido says, an image's dataURL (dataURL==an encoded string) is not natively convertible into an array of pixel data. You can accomplish your task on the client-side with html5 canvas using `context.getImageData`. [This](https://github.com/scijs/get-pixels) NodeJS script says it can do it on the server-side. Perhaps you can adapt the script for use on the client-side.

Comment: I could able to convert by using html5 canvs. Here my problem is after drawing an image into canvas the dpi has changes to 72.

Comment: Why is DPI important to your application? I think you mean pixel resolution, not DPI. DPI means dots-per-inch and is a printer measurement. BTW, canvas resolution is typically 96 pixels-per-inch, not 72 ppi. If you want greater pixel density (for monitor display) just make a larger canvas and use CSS to display the larger canvas in a smaller viewport. If you want greater pixel density (for printing) just make a larger canvas.

Comment: In my project i have sent images to server for extraction. Extraction was not done properly for images which has less than 200 dpi.

Comment: If i get the image data from canvas then the dpi of an image is 96. I got an extraction error from my server.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the way you're explaining your issues. Anyway, AFAIK, aside from 3rd party imaging tools, html5 canvas is the only way to fetch image pixels in native javascript.

Comment: @MobileDev if you do get the imagedata from a canvas, you just have the raw pixel values in an 8bit array (0-255 rgba values). There is no metadata. Hence no ppi, nor dpi information. Even when using the toDataURL method, these informations are just ignored. With your actual question, the only acceptable answer is the comment I did turned to an answer.

Comment: There is now createImageBitmap, bit requires an "<img>, <video>, or <canvas> element, a Blob, ImageData or CanvasRenderingContext2D object, or another ImageBitmap"

Answer (score 0):

Because the dataURI does represent the file (compressed), not the pixels data.